# Uninstalled Anaconda still shows up in PATH (Mac OS X)

Tags: bash, macos, python-2.7, echo, anaconda

I have installed `Anaconda` a few months ago but then uninstalled it and removed all anaconda files by using

```
rm -rf ~/anaconda
```

but when I run

```
echo $PATH
```

it still outputs a path that point to an `Anaconda` folder but when I search for it, it doesn't even exist, why is that happening?

[image]

Comment: You can remove the image and copy paste the actual `$PATH` output from console.

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think that non-existent directory are automatically
removed from `$PATH`? They are not. As an example I can make a new dir
and go there:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/new-path-dir && cd /tmp/new-path-dir
```

Add it to the `$PATH`:

```
$ PATH=/tmp/new-path-dir:$PATH
$ echo $PATH
/tmp/new-path-dir:<REST_OF_PATH>
```

Make a new `olleh.so` (`hello` spelled backwards) executable inside
it:

```
$ echo 'echo hi' > olleh.so && chmod +x olleh.so
```

Then go back to `~`:

$ cd ~

And start a `olleh.so`:

```
$ olleh.so
hi
```

Now I can safely remove `/tmp/new-path-dir`:

```
$ rm -r /tmp/new-path-dir/
```

And it still *will* be shown in my `$PATH`:

```
$ echo $PATH
/tmp/new-path-dir:<REST_OF_PATH>
```

But I won't be able to run `olleh.so` any more:

```
$ olleh.so
bash: /tmp/new-path-dir/olleh.so: No such file or directory
```

And as paths to executables are cached by `bash` I can get rid of
`olleh.so` permanently like this:

```
$ hash -r
$ olleh.so
bash: olleh.so: command not found
```